# how to decrypt creditcard detail from magtek card reader which uses 3des with DUKPT key in Android

Tags: android

The details i am getting from the magtek card reader is 
ksn ,track1,track2,track3,Track1.Encrypted,Track2.Encrypted,Track3.Encrypted,card IIN number,Magneprint status,card name ,card last4,card exp date,card svc code,session id,hashcode,device serial number
i am getting my card number in track1,2,3 data but it is encrypted (middle 6 digit).using these details how to decrypt the track1 values or how to get the key for decryption..

Comment: can you please explain how you separated track 1,2,3 and KSN from that raw data.

Comment: How did you get the svc code to be readable? When I print it it shows asteriks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please contact your Payment Processor partner, they will surely help you with the documentation.

You need to send `ksn, Track1.Encrypted,Track2.Encrypted,Track3.Encrypted,session id` to the payment process as parameters, it then returns back unmasked card number.

TATA has their own java built libraries for this purpose.

Comment: hi onkar tks for quick response.i asked my provider(Magtek) they said that i have to pay 30$ per year.they also said that since 3DES is an open ANSI standard you can create a custom encryption key and decrypt the data yourself.  We do not provide support to teach customers how to decrypt the data nor do we provide a utility other than our web service

Comment: The job if magtek is to read card data itself and it seems to be doing it fine. Reading actual card data (encrypted one ) and actually process payment is the job of payment processors. In India, TATA & ATOS origin provide this service. They will help you to get unmasked credit card number

Comment: ya that really helped me. i have sent the track1 encrypted detail to authorize.net but its not responding.is there any way to get the key which used for encryption by using the encrypted data

Comment: can u send some site links to decode or get the key used to decode

Comment: Decryption of such information is very confidential. Anyways, will look at keep you updated ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34235/discussion-between-pushparaj-and-onkar)

Comment: is every card reader providers charging to decrypt data.can u send me some mobile card reader names which doesn't charge any for decrypting

Comment: Hi Ruban, I m getting all encrypted data from magtek card reader but i am unable to find out where is track 1 , track 2 , and track 3 data. can you please help me out.

Comment: @Manikanta please refer to SDK documentation provided by the card reader